# "Parity check in progress" warning in ESXi 5

Tags: warnings, storage, vmware, esxi

After connecting 8 hard drives to RAID5 and doing Fast initialization my ESXi shows 8 warnings that say "Parity check in progress".
In old vmware forums I found that maybe RAID is still building, but why then am I allowed to use the datastore?

any ideas what this warning means and how to get rid of it?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct, the raid is still building. It might take a couple of hours, depending on:

- the raid controller,
- disk speed
- disk size.

If your raid controller doesn't have write back enabled (or doesn't support it), that time will be quite longer.